# Subquery returned more than 1 value This is not permitted when the subquery

Tags: sql-server

I use this query:

```
select * 
from Master_Shares 
where (PartnerId = (select distinct PartnerId from Master_Shares ))
```

This throws the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: What is this query supposed to be doing? It's simply filtering the rows, right? To the ones that have PartnerId set? Why won't you simply use WHERE clause to filter them out (like WHERE PartnerId is not null)?

Answer (score 3):

The error message that you get is self-explanatory: the subquery

```
select distinct PartnerId from Master_Shares
```

returns more than one value, hence its result is not *scalar* and cannot be used with the `=` operator.

You have to use `IN` operator instead:

```
select * 
from Master_Shares 
where PartnerId IN (select distinct PartnerId from Master_Shares )
```

P.S. The query seems pointless since it is essentially equivalent to:

```
select * 
from Master_Shares
```

I just leave this post as a hint towards the usage of the `IN` operator.

Comment: When using `IN` he shouldn't need `DISTINCT` either, it's probably better without, if the SQL Server query optimizer isn't smart enough to disregard it that is.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, this is probably true.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `IN` instead of `=`, that because your subquery returns more than 1 value as your error message says, that's mean you can't use `=` in following:

```
select * 
from Master_Shares 
where (PartnerId IN (select distinct PartnerId from Master_Shares ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct PartnerId from Master_Shares
```

This query will get you all the distinct PartnerId available in Master_Shares table.

Now,

```
select * from Master_Shares 
where (PartnerId = (select distinct PartnerId from Master_Shares ))
```

in Where clause you have used '=' operator which will expect only one value from your inner query. Your query will work only in that case where there is only one distinct PartnerId in your table but in the case where you will have multiple distinct PartnerId it will fail.

**Solution:-**

> You can use In clause

```
select * from Master_Shares 
    where PartnerId in (select distinct PartnerId from Master_Shares )
```

But in your case

```
select * from Master_Shares
```

will also give the same record as IN query . So I don't understand why you want to do this in this way in first place?